# Using R: Why I always get different Cohen d values?

Tags: cohens-d

Hopefully someone can help me as the question drives me completely crazy. I'm using R to calculate Cohen's d with the following code and every time I get different results.

What am doing wrong?

```
library(effsize)
treatment = rnorm(75,mean= 15.37, sd= 8.43) 
control = rnorm(75,mean=21.20, sd=8.37) 
cohen.d(treatment,control,na.rm=FALSE,pooled=TRUE,paired=FALSE)
```

Comment: I am voting to leave this open. The underlying issue is not specific to R.

Comment: Why would you expect to get the same results every time?

Answer (score 4):

The `rnorm` code generates a random normal variable, which changes each time you run your code.

To make the code reproducible, use `set.seed()`, for example `set.seed(1)`.

Comment: Thank you! Iam using mes() now as Im interested in constant d values and not in a simulation. For what could it be good?